# Запись кода программы (генератор случайных чисел), в одну строчку

Tags: haskell

Есть простой код, который генерирует случайное число в диапазоне и выглядит примерно так

```
import System.Random

main :: IO()
main = do
  randGen <- getStdGen
  print $ fst $ randomR(0 :: Int, 9) randGen
```

Надо записать это в одну строчку, чтоб не использовать `main = do`

```
import System.Random

main :: IO()
main = print $ fst $ randomR(0 :: Int, 9) (getStdGen)
```

Вот так уже не получается. Знаю, что это не работает из-за того, что `getStdGen` не чистая функция и нужно использовать, наверное, что-то типа `=<<` и `>>=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку `getStdGen :: IO StdGen`, к нему можно "применить" `randomR` посредством `fmap`:

```
randomR(0 :: Int, 9) <$> getStdGen   :: IO (Int, StdGen)
```

Потом к этому результату можно прилепить `fst` тем же способом:

```
fst <$> (randomR(0 :: Int, 9) <$> getStdGen)   :: IO Int
```

Или, пользуясь тождеством `g <$> (f <$> x) == g . f <$> x`:

```
fst . randomR(0 :: Int, 9) <$> getStdGen   :: IO Int
```

Однако `print` отличается от `fst` и `randomR` тем, что возвращает не "чистое" значение, а `IO`. Поэтому, если его попытаться прилепить тем же способом, получится вложенное `IO`:

```
print . fst . randomR(0 :: Int, 9) <$> getStdGen   :: IO (IO ())
```

К счастью есть другая операция - `=<<` - которая работает почти так же как `<$>`, но только ещё "разворачивает" монад:

```
print =<< fst . randomR(0 :: Int, 9) <$> getStdGen   :: IO ()
```